# How can my Discord bot handle multiple inputs?

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I want to call a function after receiving several messages from a user in a text channel, but I don't know how to do this.

```
startGame = False
async def on_message(message): # when a new message is detected in the server
    if message.author == client.user: ## don't respond to own message sent by the bot
        return

    if not startGame:
        if message.content == "?startGame": ## start asking for several inputs once user wants to start the game
             await message.channel.send("age?") ## i want to ask for the user's age
             ## ask several other things and store them etc
             startGame = True
```

However, I don't know how to store the user's age now, as the bot will send "age?" in the server and then `on_message` will be called again but won't do anything in this case, so I can't use the user's input

Comment: you should probably define a class User() that can store values...

Answer (score 0):

in order to store the value of their input for age, you would set the `.send()` equal to a variable, like so:

`msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message')`

when the user inputs their age, it is now stored into the `msg` variable to be used elsewhere.